# AWS lambda function get timeout without any error message When it connect S3 SDK sometimes

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

AWS lambda function get timeout without any error message When it  connect S3 SDK sometimes.

1. When try to S3.getObject(), Lambda function stop until timeout without any error message.
2. Only sometimes, I get this happen even I use same parameter, same code.
3. I used try catch code already. If something wrong, the code make error msg but, It was not.

The point is that the lambda function makes problems 'sometimes'.
Normally, It works well. But, It stop suddenly.

Please help me this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zGKj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2TSO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twgYe.png)

```html
2020-07-30T16:45:22.003+09:00
START RequestId: 2c1dcd43-41f6-5d95-a862-9adf3d267ecf Version: $LATEST

2020-07-30T16:45:22.009+09:00
2020-07-30T07:45:22.009Z 2c1dcd43-41f6-5d95-a862-9adf3d267ecf INFO fileKeys : [ '701bcf80-ed63-46d4-9524-d38a14a74fe0.dwg' ]

2020-07-30T16:45:22.009+09:00
2020-07-30T07:45:22.009Z 2c1dcd43-41f6-5d95-a862-9adf3d267ecf INFO getObject drawingFile 701bcf80-ed63-46d4-9524-d38a14a74fe0.dwg

2020-07-30T16:45:22.019+09:00
2020-07-30T07:45:22.018Z 2c1dcd43-41f6-5d95-a862-9adf3d267ecf INFO before getObject

2020-07-30T16:45:22.020+09:00
2020-07-30T07:45:22.020Z 2c1dcd43-41f6-5d95-a862-9adf3d267ecf INFO before createReadStream

2020-07-30T16:45:22.021+09:00
2020-07-30T07:45:22.021Z 2c1dcd43-41f6-5d95-a862-9adf3d267ecf INFO before pipe

2020-07-30T16:45:52.032+09:00
END RequestId: 2c1dcd43-41f6-5d95-a862-9adf3d267ecf

2020-07-30T16:45:52.032+09:00
REPORT RequestId: 2c1dcd43-41f6-5d95-a862-9adf3d267ecf Duration: 30027.38 ms Billed Duration: 30000 ms Memory Size: 3008 MB Max Memory Used: 31 MB

2020-07-30T16:45:52.032+09:00
2020-07-30T07:45:52.032Z 2c1dcd43-41f6-5d95-a862-9adf3d267ecf Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
```

Here is the code

```js
exports.getObject = async (type, fileKey) => {
  try {
    const config = env[type]();
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileName = `/tmp/${fileKey}`;
      const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName, 'binary');
      const s3Stream = s3
        .getObject({
          Bucket: config.origin,
          Key: fileKey,
        })
        .createReadStream();

      s3Stream
        .on('error', function (err) {
          console.error('s3Stream  : ', err);
          fileStream.end();
          reject(err);
        })
        .on('data', (data) => {
          // console.log('data stream...');
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          console.log('s3Stream read end');
        });

      fileStream
        .on('error', function (err) {
          console.error('fileStream  : ', err);
          fileStream.end();
          reject(err);
        })
        .on('close', function () {
          console.log('fileStream Done.');
          resolve('success');
        });

      s3Stream.pipe(fileStream)
        .on('error', function (err) {
          console.error('File Stream:', err);
          reject(err);
        })
        .on('close', function () {
          console.log('Pipe Done.');
        });;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw (error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you please the errors and code as text, not screenshots?

Comment: Is the Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, why was this decision made? Also, if it is connected to a VPC, is the Lambda function connected to multiple subnets, or just one? Are these subnets 'private subnets', 'public subnets', or a mixture of the two?

Comment: @Marcin I just added them

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes Lambda connect to VPC and 4 subnets and mixture.

Comment: So lambda function only sometimes does not work? lambda in a VPC does not have internet connection. How do you make it that it somtimes work, or not?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, The lambda function does not work sometimes. The lambda function connect with S3 and EKS Services.

I can know easily when It works or not. Cuz, when It does not works, Lambda function stop until timeout (50s). When It does work, make log and Object is moved in S3.

Comment: S3 and EKS requires internet access. Lambda in VPC will not be able to access these, unless you setup VPC gateway or EKS VPC endpoint, or using the NAT gateway. Have you done that?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, I just check them. these have been set up. 
mystery point is that Lambda function move object different bucket and send request to ESK services successfully. I think, If I didn't set up, the lambda function must not work always or make error. But, it's not. Just wait the get object line with out any error msg

Comment: That's correct. It would always timeout if internet was the issue. Maybe there is something different about the objects that fail? Maybe you are not their owner, or the moving takes long time?

Comment: @Marcin unfortunately, If I move same file, the problem is same... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your Lambda function is connected to a mixture of private and public subnets.

When calling AWS services, Internet access is required. This can either be obtained via:

- Connecting the Lambda function to **private subnets** and having a NAT Gateway in the public subnet(s), with the Route Table of the private subnets sending traffic destined for `0.0.0.0/0` to the NAT Gateway, *or*
- Use VPC Endpoints within the VPC to allow direct connectivity to the AWS service(s)

If the Lambda function connects to a *public subnet*, it will not be able to use the NAT Gateway. This will cause connections to AWS to timeout. The random behaviour might be related to which subnet the Lambda function is using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try it then I will let you know the result :)

Comment: @MJKim did you fix this in the end? could you please share the solution? thanks